# Ember-data in more complex routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember-data model called `goal` where the list view maps back to the RESTful API at:

> GET /api/users/[id]/goal

and a singular goal record would map to:

> GET /api/users/[id]/goal/[goalId]

What I'm wondering is ... what's the most graceful way of configuring this using ember-data's RESTAdapter? What I've done so far is set the application adapter (aka, `adapters/application.js`) to a namespace of 'api' so that offset is taken care of.

What I'm not sure of is how to ensure that the `/users/[id]` part of the URL is included. Obviously this is a dynamic segment which makes it more complicated although I suspect its actually not hard at all but I'm just not sure how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Its not 100% clear what the user-id is, since user always sounds like authentication. So there are two scenarios:

#### The User is *not* about security, but can be selected on then Website before accessing the goals.

In that case you have a user model with a `goals: hasMany('goal')` and you should access the goals over the relation from the User. You have probably a nested Route and can access to the surrounding `UserRoute`'s model with `this.modelFor('user')` from the route, and then access the `goals`.

On the adapter the interesting function is then [findHasMany](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findHasMany). Another simple way is just add a `links` object on the User with `goals: '/api/users/thisUsersId/goals/'.

For the single goal the goal should be accessible with `/api/goals/id` since the `id` should be absolutely unique.

#### You use the User for authentication and authorization.

In this case I would recommend you to use ember-simple-auth and implement a custom authorizer. Here you can implement the `authorize` function and modify the `jQuery`-`XmlHttpRequest` to contains the user part.